# Using Google Maps to track total time spent at a specific location

Tags: google-maps, location

I'm trying to use the location data of Google Maps to track the amount of time spent at a specific location. My aim is to calculate the total number of hours at my place of work, since Google Maps provides an estimate of the time I arrived and left there.
I've been able to export my Maps location data using Google Takeout, but these resulting files do not appear partiularly useful. Ideally what I want is to be able to put into a spreadsheet the time I have arrived and left my place of work each day. Is there a relatively easy way to fish this out of my location data without having to manually enter the time each day?
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"but these resulting files do not appear particularly useful"* please edit your question to clarify what you mean by this.